# Python Requests trying to post data to Laravel

Tags: python, laravel, laravel-4, python-requests

I'm trying to send post data like login user using python requests

But I got and error when login success from Laravel it like Laravel can't handle session for requests to use

My code to send post data

```
s=requests.Session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

URL = 'http://test.dev/api/login'

s.get(URL)
csrftoken = s.cookies['csrf']
print csrftoken
login_data = dict(username='test', password='testtest', _token=csrftoken)
ra=s.post(URL, data=login_data, headers = headers)
print ra.request.headers
```

if password wrong it return a right error message

but if password right laravel return and 500 error code

```
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
unlink(/var/www/test/app/storage/sessions/f830674995ed8aae82a729dc9986bcd7de3ec81b): No      such file or directory
```

I don't understand why python can't handle laravel session.

Comment: You are getting a  `No   such file or directory` error, I doubt that is requests fault.

Comment: This isn't a Python problem; the *Laravel server* is having a problem.

Comment: I use this "with requests.session() as s:" and it working now. don't understand y it working.