# How to use Python Requests session to a longtime?

Tags: python, python-requests

I don't know how to ask this question but I will explain it.

I use Requests to login to website like this

```
URL = 'http://test.dev/api/login'
with requests.session() as s:
    s.get(URL)
    login_data = {'username': 'test', 'password': 'testtest'}
    ra=s.post(URL, data=login_data)
    # Now I got session and cookie I can go to another pages like
    r=s.get('http://test.dev/api/user/1')
```

When login success the server sent the session and cookie back.

But if I go out the the loop "with" I must login again?

Question is how can I go another page with out the "with" loop ?

```
EDIT1:
```

EDIT: I try to use at s=requests.Session() firstime

but it error like this:

[Python Requests trying to post data to Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125643/python-requests-trying-to-post-data-to-laravel?noredirect=1#comment39106411_25125643)

```
EDIT2:
```

I try to use s = requests.session() again and it work I don't know why = =

Thank you all.

Comment: Just instantiate a session and don't use it as a context manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Daniel's answer the `with` block is a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement). It will open a new context for you, in your case your call to `requests.session()`. Once the block is completed the the context it will be closed.

In your example once the line `r=s.get(...)` is completed there is no more code for the context so it is closed. For example these two blocks achieve the same result:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write('Hello, world')
```

and

```
fh = open('file.txt', 'w')
fh.write('Hello, world')
fh.close()
```

Comment: I use s = requests.session() and can't login to the server.

Comment: I try to use s = requests.session() again and it work I don't know why = =

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to close the session at the end, don't use a `with` block. Just do

```
s = requests.session()
```

and pass `s` around as necessary.

Comment: I use s = requests.session() and can't login to the server

Comment: I try to use s = requests.session() again and it work I don't know why = =

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on this a little more:
The " Python Requests trying to post data to Laravel " error simply means there is a problem with the Laravel server - not a python issue.

```
s=requests.session()
```

should work just fine and you can use that "s" session object wherever you wish. You can even pass the "s" object as a parameter to other functions.

Using the

```
with requests.session() as s:
```

merely limits the scope of "s" object to the indented block of code under the "with"... You can pass the "s" to functions within that block, but coding outside of that block leaves the context of that "s" object.